# How to create an array for the values of each column in my SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, json, database

I have an SQL DB that has the columns: Subject, Type, Year, Season.
And each subject has several types, and each type has several years and each year several seasons.
And I'm trying to code in PHP something that will create for me an array that contains what are the seasons for each year for each type of each Subject... so I'm trying to end up with something like that:

```json
{
   Subject1: {
       Subject: "{NAME OF SUBJECT1}",
       Types: [
           {
               Type: "{Type1 for Subject1}",
               Years: [ 
                         {
                              Year: {"Year1 for Type1 and Subject1"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                         {
                              Year: {"Year2 for the type and subject"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                     ]
           },
           {
               Type: "{Type2 for this subject}",
               Years: [ 
                         {
                              Year: {"Year1 for Type2 and Subject1"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                         {
                              Year: {"Year2 for Type2 and Subject1"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                     ]
           }

       ]
   },
   Subject2: {
       Subject: "{NAME OF SUBJECT2}",
       Types: {
           {
               Type: "{Type1 for Subject2}",
               Years: [ 
                         {
                              Year: {"Year1 for Type1 and Subject2"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                         {
                              Year: {"Year2 for Type2 and subject2"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                     ]
           },
           {
               Type: "{Type2 for this subject}",
               Years: [ 
                         {
                              Year: {"Year1 for Type2 and Subject2"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                         {
                              Year: {"Year2 for Type2 and Subject2"},
                              Season: { "{Season1}", "{Season2}" }
                         },
                     ]
           }

       }
   }
}
```

and so on...
I have no idea how to do it, and any answer would be very appreciated! :)
Many Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you are still expected to make an effort of your own. If you have no idea where to start, then SO is not the right place for you - you need a tutorial. If you've tried something, but it fails, please share your code and explain the problem.

Comment: @El_Vanja I do know php and sql, I tried to make a select request to the database and then with some of for in for loops and then make this array, every time I create a new request with `... WHERE Subject = {$subject} AND Type = {$type}`. but it doesn't work. So I do know what I'm doing and I was just trying to explain that I need your help... Thanks again

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a poor problem description. What exactly doesn't work and in what way? I'd suggest you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources to understand how to formulate a good question.

Comment: @El_Vanja I really appreciate that you really answer me, but please if you know the answer please say it. if not just say you don't know and it's ok, but I've done my research and I got to an end place; I can say to you I can do it with tons of for loops but I think there's a better solution, So this is why I'm asking you. Again, Thank you.

Comment: It's not a matter of knowing how to do it. Your question lacks details for anyone to help you. You haven't given an example of your data, you haven't specified in what way the data is retreived, you haven't shared any code... Maybe your query needs optimization. Maybe your algorithm. Maybe both. But you haven't shared any of those details, so how do you expect someone to answer?

Comment: @El_Vanja Ok, you're right I'll try to edit my question.